# Getting Dialog to Work Upon Successful Submission

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to make my form display a dialog box (possibly via Javascript) upon successful submission of my form. How do I do this?

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.setDefaults({
});

$().ready(function() {
    // validate alphaRegister form on keyup and submit
    $("#alphaRegister").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "*"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <form id="alphaRegister" action="src/php/newSubscriber.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="cemail" value="" class="required" />
        <div style="float:right; margin:0 5px 2px 0;"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="" /></div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your server side script to add a JS variable to your page once the form has been submited/processed and then in your `$().ready` function, check to see if this variable is set. If it is then display your dialog box.

**Update:**

To do this you will need to set a PHP variable `formSubmitResult` to true/false or 1/0 if it passes/fails your PHP validation routine.

Then put this in the head of the page that you submit to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var submitIsValid=<?php echo formSubmitResult;?>;
$().ready(function() {
 if(submitIsValid)
 {
  alert("Submission was valid!"); // or some code to open your custom dialog box
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Which language? JSP, ColdFusion, ASP, PHP?

Comment: I think you need to do some research and ask a better question.